# is there any way to do reverse comparison using regex in JSON path

Tags: regex, reverse, contains, jsonpath

I m trying to write JSON path expression using regex, it works fine when i fetch the JSON node and compare with regex, but in my case i have to compare regex with JSON node,
I get the JSON node from JSON file and real path from my app, i have to check whether real path contains JSON node.
RealPath=/secure/api/sso/login
JSON NODE Path=/api/sso/login

My JSON looks like this

```
{
    "path": [{
            "relativepath": "/api/sso/login",
            "transformation": "true"
        },
        {
            "relativepath": "/api/sso/logout",
            "transformation": "false"
        }
    ]
}
```

and JSON Path which is working for me fine is $..[?(@.relativepath =~ /^.*/api/sso/login.*$/)]

I have to check in JSON PATH whether **/secure/api/sso/login contains /api/sso/login**(fetched using JSON Path)

Comment: Which language you're working with ?

Comment: Its not language, Its a tool called API gateway, we have filter, where we can add JSON path in it, It works in jayway